# What is the best way to change drives through command line on a mac?

Tags: macos, command-line

What is the best way to change drives through command line on a mac?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What do you mean by change drives?

If you mean changing directory so that you can use the files on an external drive, they're mounted in `/Volumes`, so if you wanted to work in the root of a disk called Foo, you'd go `cd /Volumes/Foo`.

If you mean ejecting a drive so you can unplug it, `hdiutil unmount /Volumes/[drive name]` is what you want, so to unmount a disk called Foo, you'd go `hdiutil unmount /Volumes/Foo`.

Comment: There is no such thing as drive letters, one working directory per drive and the need to type e.g. `C:` on Mac OS X, as there is on Windows.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea that I was talking about drive letters - hopefully things are clearer now.

Comment: Sorry, meant that as an addition, as I suspect this concept caused the user's confusion (but your edit is useful anyway). If you reply to comments, please use @-syntax, e.g. `@DanielBeck` or `@Daniel`, so the user you reply to gets a notification.

Answer (score 7):

You don't; you just go to another mounted volume.

```
cd /Volumes/"Some Volume Name Here"
```